# Is CloudFormation idempotent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I read in many places on internet that CloudFormation is not idempotent, but I cannot find any example that proves this fact.

Could you please provide me an example that runs a resource to prove that CloudFormation is not idempotent ?

Comment: id (instance_id, vpc_id, securitygroup_id, etc) are  different

Comment: @BMW If you use `create-stack` will generate, for example, security group id. But if you use `update-stack` over the same template, it is idempotent: no resource will change (won't be duplications, errors and on, the infrastructure state is what you would expect).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The definition of [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning) according to Wikipedia is as follows:

> In computer science, the term idempotent is used more comprehensively
>   to describe an operation that will produce the same results if
>   executed once or multiple times.

CloudFormation is considered not idempotent in several aspects of its behavior:

- Calling the create API for a stack that already exists will result in an error
- Calling the update API with an unchanged CloudFormation stack results in an error
- Creating and deleting the same stack again will result in creating resources with different ARNs for IAM Users, Security Group IDs, EC2 Instance IDs, VPC IDs, etc...
- Resources modified outside of CloudFormation will not be changed back to original values if existing stack is updated with existing content

However, from a high level one of the main reasons to use CloudFormation is so you represent your infrastructure as code so you can use it to produce the same infrastructure repeatedly.  That is almost identical to the original definition of idempotent, but the distinction is on the *multiple times* part here.  As listed above when using the same stack and applying on top of it or deleting a stack and recreating it, technically you are not getting the **exact** same results, but from a practical standpoint this is completely understandable and often perfectly acceptable.

Comment: How would you then automate Cloudformation script in a CI pipeline if you can't rerun the same script twice? I would like to script my infra together with application code, so that both could evolve over time alongside, but I can't see a way to run it multiple times

Comment: They way I configure my CI pipeline to deploy CFN scripts even when nothing changes is to include in the property something like the Jenkins build id.  I then use this I'd as an input to something that will always change like a tag.  This allows the CFN to update and deploy with every build.

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure whether this answer will be useful as the question has been posted 2 years ago. Better late than never.

AWS CloudFormation has changed a lot in these 2 years. Right now, I can say for sure that it's API calls are idempotent.

Have a look at these API calls:

1. [CreateStack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html)
2. [UpdateStack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateStack.html)
3. [DeleteStack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteStack.html)

You will find that there is an optional parameter called **ClientRequestToken**. This provides idempotency to the API calls. It's the token that client provides to tell the CloudFormation service that it is not making a new API call. As long as you use the same token and keep making the call with rest of the parameters same, CloudFormation knows that you are only retrying the call.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudformation is idempotent provided you have not made updates to an already completed stack, if there are changes then it will update ,now updating a resource might require deletion of it and creation or an update w/o creation of a new resource

To know more read about cfn-hup process, this will help you